# Sidebar toggle effect is breaking my menu items

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm creating a very simple sidenav for a mobile app. I followed [this example](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_sidenav).

Everything is working fine, except that when I close the menu, if you pay attention, my menu items `<a>` tags are "breaking" as the sidebar shrinks back to place.  If you see the example code from above, their menu items do not break.

[Here's my code.](https://codepen.io/paulamourad/pen/KBpJRJ)

```js
function openNav() {
                document.getElementById("sidenav").style.width = "80%";
            }

            function closeNav() {
                document.getElementById("sidenav").style.width = "0";
            }
```

```css
/*-- Top Navbar --*/
.top-navbar {
 width: 100%;
 height: 8%;
 background-color: #E4E4E4;
 font-size: 1.5em;
 padding-top: 2%;
}

.top-navbar span {
 margin-left: 4%;
 padding-top: 2%;
 color: #2c2c2c;
}

/*-- Sidebar --*/
.sidenav {
 height: 100%;
 width: 0;
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 1;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 background-color: #E4E4E4;
 overflow-x: hidden;
 transition: 0.5s;
 padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
 padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 1em;
 color: #2C2C2C;;
 display: block;
 transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
 color: #9F2241;
}

/*.sidenav a:before {
 content: "";
 display: block;
 background: url(../img/icono-retirar.svg) no-repeat;
 width: 20px;
 height: 20px;
 float: left;
 margin-left: 0 6px 0 0;
}
*/

.sidenav .closebtn {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 right: 25px;
 font-size: 36px;
 margin-left: 50px;
 color: #2c2c2c;
}
```

```html
<div id="sidenav" class="sidenav">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
            <a href="#">Haz un retiro</a>
            <a href="#">Invita un amigo</a>
            <a href="#">Ayuda</a>
            <a href="#">Términos y condiciones</a>
            <a href="#">Cerrar sesión</a>
        </div>

        <div class="top-navbar">
            <span onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</span>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `white-space:nowrap;` to your `.sidenav a` css rule.